# Raspberry Pi B+; Problems with the autostart of browser

Tags: midori, web

Having problems with autostarting a browser at the b+

I tried like every imagineable way listed on the web;

```
Midori Browser Autostart -benjaminroesner.com
Midori Browser Autostart -Ibex (over etc/xdg/lxsession/LXDE/autostart)
autostart of the browser over etc/xdg/lxsession/LXDE-pi -forum raspberry-pi
```

None of the worked except of solution of 1, but it only opened a little window at the right top of the monitor.
The other solutions did end with a black screen after restart.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you're using the wrong file. The file used to configure auto-starting items for LXDE is:

```
/home/pi/.config/lxsession/LXDE-pi/autostart
```

Just add `@midori` to that file, and you should be up and running.